# Find the shaded region and area of the shaded region

Tags: circles

> In the diagram below, $CAD$ is a sector with centre $A$ and $EBD$ is a semicircle with diameter $ED$. Given that $AB=18cm$ and angle $CAD=\pi/3$ radian.
>   Find
>
> (a) The perimeter of the shaded region.
>
> (b) The area of the shaded region.

[image]

I'm assuming that $AB=CD$ and have worked out that $CD=37.704cm$
Please help as it is midnight in my region and I would need to hand in my homework tomorrow.

Comment: Please rotate your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $O=(E+D)/2$ be the center of the semi-circle then $BO$ is orthogonal to $AB$.Then $\angle CAD=\pi/3$ implies that $\triangle ABO$ is a right triangle with angles $30^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-90^{\circ}$.  Moreover, $\triangle ACD$ is equilateral.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thank you very much